# How do i avoid PHP interfering with HTML output?

Tags: php, html, web, formatting

I have a pretty weird error that I have not been able to find any other information on anywhere else, So I'm hoping you might be able to point me in the right direction.

I am trying to center this table and for some reason when it's run within a PHP file it get's skewed to the right - let me show you what I have got:

Here are live previews of the table being aligned perfectly center in pure HTML and here it is being run with just one PHP tag pushing it to the right

Pure HTML - http://codepen.io/csarsam/pen/wAteD

Here it is with one PHP tag - http://codepad.viper-7.com/1mpN95

Comment: I really love digging thru hundreds of lines of messy code.

Comment: please readup about using template techniques, Smarty is a good template engine to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the max-width of #content on both the files !!!
in one its 990px and in other its 660px.
i checked it on localhost and it did solved the problem.
just a minor mistake.

Comment: WOW thanks it was worth the -5!